# Background not showing up in java processing project

Tags: java, background, applet, processing, project

I think I'm doing everything right in my code but my background won't show up in my processing project, here is my code.

```
package finalproject;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class FinalProject extends PApplet {
    PImage background;
    PImage player;
    public void setup() {
        size(1360, 1080);
        player = loadImage("player.png");       
        background  = loadImage("rust.png");
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(background);
        image(player, 500, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens instead? Are the images being loaded? Try printing out the values of their width and height. Do they show if you just use the `image()` function instead of the `background()` function?

Comment: It is just gray

Comment: You're going to need to [debug](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your sketch. It sounds like your images aren't being loaded correctly. Have you tried printing out info about them to see if they're being loaded? Where is Processing looking for the image files? Where are they located instead?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, so the problem is with where your files are located. You need to figure out exactly where the `loadImage()` function is looking.

Comment: @EricZeBaws2 have you solved your problem yet? This could be an issue with using processing outside it's' IDE.

Comment: No, I have not but I just decided to draw the thing with code like rect() etc

Answer (score 0):

Processing expects files to be inside a `data` directory next to the code.

You're presumably running this from an IDE like Eclipse instead of the Processing editor, so where you put that `data` directory depends on how your code is setup. And you haven't posted a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it's hard to help you with that.

But basically, you need to debug your sketch to figure out exactly where Processing is looking for the files. Then you need to move the files there. This is probably something simple like putting them inside a `data` directory.

If you still can't get it working, please post a MCVE along with a screenshot or a description of your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the processing IDE than the data folder should be located in your sketch folder next to all the .pde files. Make sure that the image you are using has the same resolution as the sketch window. If you are still having issues I would recommend that you try moving your setup and draw methods out of your class and into the main processing sketch.